# A trigger does not work properly

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

the task: Write a trigger that checks to add a schedule to an event that exists,
And that the room is not occupied for a new schedule. If the setting is correct, the insertion will be allowed. Otherwise, you will be entitled
And there will be an error message to the user. The trigger's name will be
TRIGF1 () the trigger function.

Unfortunately, the only exception that i see every time is the second exception about the room being occupied. the first one does not work at all (the one that checks if an event already exists in the tables which is the case that it's allowed to add it) 
what could be the logical issue? thank you so much for the support.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigf1() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $schedule_trigger$
   BEGIN
    IF (NOT((new.eid = (select reid from revent where new.eid = reid)) or (new.eid = (select seid from sevent where new.eid = seid))))
    THEN raise exception 'ERROR! event id number % does not exist in table revent and not in sevent', new.eid;
    ELSIF (exists 
        (select tsrange(schedule.sdate + schedule.stime, schedule.sdate + schedule.stime+ schedule.duration, '[]') && 
        tsrange(new.sdate + new.stime, new.sdate + new.stime+ new.duration, '[]')
         from schedule
        where new.rno=schedule.rno and new.bno=schedule.bno))
        THEN raise exception 'ERROR! The room is already occupied during this time';
    ELSE
    return new;
    END IF;
   END;
$schedule_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: "`...'[]') && tsrange(...`" does that even compile? The logical and operator is `AND` normally.

Comment: @stickybit that is `overlap` operator for range types and it returns boolean. It makes no sense tho when used as part of SELECT inside `EXISTS` operator, since it does not care what value is returned.